# Can we add global method or rest endpoint in locked package patch version?

Tags: apex, managed-package, apexrest, global-methods, global

We can't add new components to the package while creating the patch version of locked package.
We have a requirement, where we need to add the global method or rest endpoint. Is it possible through the patch version?
Does Salesforce treat new global method or new rest endpoint as new component?

Comment: No, you cannot add new globals or REST methods in a patch. I presume that by "locked" you mean "managed"...

Comment: Reading straight from the documentation - You can’t add Apex access modifiers, such as virtual or global.
This includes classes , methods etc. Even inner classes will not work.